# Emulate Emacs-like Mode

Tags: vimscript

I'm used to Emacs different modes, that is:

- Setting up functions/setting once entering a specific Mode
- Renaming the statusbar with the name of the Mode
- "Cleaning up" (resetting setting to normal ones, etc) once exiting said Mode

Now, I'm really unsure on how to emulate the above workflow in vimscript. I recall seeing some vimscripts that changed the statusline/bar when they were being used, and changed it back once they weren't used, but not sure I recall them.

Let's take for example something simple:

```
set statusline=helloworld
```

How could I make it so the above get set, but once *some* key are pressed (say "C-k") it revert back to the old statusline?

Here the following ideas to "emulate" the above:

- Using tempfile to remember state/Mode being used
- Setting up mapping for both exiting and entering a Mode (while making it so they can check if Mode is already used or not)

I have a vague idea on how to do it, but I'd like to know others advice/opinions in how this could be done/improved (with maybe some existing plugins/snippet that could help in doing so).

I mainly want this because I find that I always unset/reset/set specific settings based on certain "workflow" I'm doing, and so Emacs's Mode workflow came to mind.

Any help/feedback appreciated.

Comment: What the mode should accomplish may help: ftplugins, syntax, ftdetect, etc. cover many things emacs modes can be used for (AFAICT), at least for major modes. For some types of “minor modes” it often tends to be some plugin + popular statusline integrations (and a standalone statuslone function if the author things about folks who dont use a statusline plugin). OTOH what you are looking for sounds like some sort of toggle-able plugin? You would typically use a global (or window/buffer/tab/script) variable to remember the current state of the plugin. It’s a bit ad-hoc...

Comment: ...I’ll try to cover some more detail in an answer at some point.

Comment: yeah, what you said is on-point (especially the part about ` toggle-able plugin`). @D.BenKnoble